# C programming and array ,matrix manipulation

Tags: c, arrays, matrix

I am trying to take an online test on techgig.com .
The problem is to find the minimum path from top left of the matrix to the bottom right.
I am trying to code this using C language.
The minimumcost function is already given as and I am not allowed to change this .

```
char* minumumcost(char* input1[],int input2)
```

where input1 is the matrix and input2 is the number of rows in matrix.

However with my limited knowledge of C , I only know how to manipulate a matrix when it is declared as a two dimensional array.

With two dimensional array I intend to do the following operation.

Here the cost matrix is cost[10][10]
\
while(point1!=n && point2!=n)
      {

```
 if(cost[a][j+1]<cost[a+1][j] && cost[a][j+1]<cost[a+1][j+1])
{  
     min=cost[a][j+1];
     s[k]='R';
     k++;
     j++;
     point1=a;
     point2=j;
}
else if(cost[a+1][j]<cost[a+1][j+1] && cost[a+1][j]<cost[a][j+1])
{   

   min=cost[a+1][j];
   s[k]='B';
   k++;
   a++;
   point1=a;
   point2=j;
} 
else  if(cost[a+1][j+1]<cost[a+1][j] && cost[a+1][j+1]<cost[a][j+1])
    { 
        min=cost[a+1][j];
        s[k]='D'; 
         a++;
         j++;  
         k++;
          point1=a;
   point2=j;
    } 
            }
```

\
An example shows that the input to the matrix is given in this form.
{5#2#3#2,8#5#5#3,1#4#7#6,3#3#6#5},4
where 4 is the no of rows and the remaining is the elements of the row .

The question is how do I do this by using input1[] ?
Please help me soon.
The test has a time limit.

Answer (score 1):

The function accepts an array of `char*`. Note that, in C, arrays and pointers can be used interchangably most of the time.

If you declared a pointer like `char* p;` you could use it just like an array: `p[5]`. So in your case, `char* input[]` is quite the same as an array of arrays of `char`: `input[2][5]` will take element #2 from the array (yielding a `char*`!) and from that element #5.
Or, even more explicitly, you could as well write

```
char* row = input[2];
char element = row[5];
```

Yet, how many elements each row of the matrix will have cannot be told from what you posted. Is it a square matrix, are the rows represented as `\0` terminated strings? You'll have to check the test question for that info.

Comment: When writing `char[] rowArray = row;`, you must have had some other language than C in mind.